# Resize DIV to only show complete lines of text

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, hide, truncate

**Description**
I have a div with a fixed height and another div with text. I need the div with text to be the same height as the other div.

**What I can do**

I can set a height to the text div and overflow hidden

**The problem**

It cuts the last line in half in some cases. It should not show half lines.

**Example code**

http://jsfiddle.net/LCQHb/

**HTML code (if jsfiddle don't work)**

```
<div class="long">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis quam sem. Nulla ultricies ultrices nisi, eu aliquam tellus accumsan sed. Praesent sapien mauris, fermentum non aliquam non, congue fermentum massa. Donec diam magna, tristique in luctus dignissim, mattis vitae enim.</p>

<h3>Morbi condimentum</h3>

<p>Fusce egestas aliquam tellus. Fusce dignissim, sapien non euismod adipiscing, odio tortor condimentum mi, at ultrices ligula lectus elementum ante. Pellentesque quis velit at odio venenatis mollis vitae molestie diam. Mauris imperdiet tristique adipiscing. Aliquam ornare tincidunt arcu, nec venenatis nisi mollis in. Proin euismod tempor elit, ut porta mauris euismod vel. Vestibulum congue ullamcorper dolor, a pellentesque nisl interdum non.</p>
<p>Phasellus at mollis tortor. Phasellus eget velit sit amet quam ultricies pretium quis nec augue. Suspendisse vel ante metus. Maecenas venenatis tristique lacus, pulvinar congue eros commodo ut. Donec vitae venenatis magna. Pellentesque posuere orci vitae nisi sagittis rutrum. Donec non mi nec tellus tincidunt malesuada. Nullam ornare ultricies ultrices. Donec mauris augue, pretium eget iaculis eget, tincidunt sit amet libero.</p>
</div>
<div class="short">
</div>
```

​
**CSS code**

```
.short, .long {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

.short {
    background: #eee;
    height: 210px;
}
.long {
    background: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

**JS code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var height = $('.short').height();
    $('.long').height(height);
});​
```

**Question**

- How do I hide the last line if it's cut in half?
- If not. Is there a jQuery plugin to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LCQHb/13/

This is a quick and dirtiest solution from a novice. Please have a look.

Sample Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var height = $('.short').height();


var x = $('.short').height() % $('.long').css('line-height').replace("px", "");

 $('.long').height(height - x);
 });
```

Comment: Let me know if this is not your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.
I am not aware of anything that does that, in jquery or else.
What you could do is :

- let height be the div height you want
- compute the closest multiple of line-height below height
- display the text div with this multiple height
- add a new blank div to fill in the gap, which is height minus the closest multiple

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

That was a great question, one of those things that really gets you thinking.  I've come up with some kind of solution, but you need to control some aspects of the element (and I'm not sure what it'd be like incorporating other elements like headings etc in the **.long** element), but here you go.  I don't think it's possible to get a scalable, 100% accurate solution to this problem - but then again I haven't exhausted all possibilities so this is the best I've got for now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var target_height = 65;
    var div_height = parseInt($(".long").height());
    var font_height = parseInt($(".long").css("font-size"));
    var line_height = font_height + 4;

    $(".long").css("line-height", line_height + "px");

    while ((target_height % line_height) !== 0) {
        target_height++;
    }

    $(".long").css("height", target_height + "px");
    $(".short").css("height", target_height + "px");

});​
```

[Here's the jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tJzdE/). Try playing around with the **target_height** variable, you should see you never get incomplete lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I use to get equal heights of two columns, you could use it here:

```
function equalHeight(group) {
   tallest = 0;
   group.each(function() {
      thisHeight = $(this).height();
      if(thisHeight > tallest) {
         tallest = thisHeight;
      }
   });
   group.height(tallest);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   equalHeight($(".long"));
   equalHeight($(".short"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use jQuery. You can solve it using just CSS.

Write the two divs `short`, `long` under the `content` div. Remove the height from `short`. Set fixed height to `content`. Use the CSS properties `line-height` and `overflow` in the `short` div to show that remaining half line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some ellipsis plugins will be a good solution ? 
For example: http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/
It's for inserting ellipsis for long texts, but also works for cutting half-lines